# Redirect misinterpret route

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect

I have a redirect that should work when a video is deleted from my app, `$this->redirect('/Admin/Dashboard/Videos/Delete');`, but cake is trying to take me to a controller called `admin`, saying that admincontroller does not exist, my flash message does not fire aswell, as it should. I have a similar rredirect, `this->redirect('/Admin/Dashboard/Videos/Upload');`, that is working perfectly but this one isn't and I also tried using `/Admin/Dashboard/Videos/Delete/:page'`, but it didn't work either. How should it be to work properly?
I am using Cake2.4.4.

**Routes**

```
Router::connect('/Admin/Dashboard/Videos/Upload', array('controller' => 'galleries', 'action' => 'uploadVideos'));
Router::connect('/Admin/Dashboard/Videos/Delete/:page', array('controller' => 'galleries', 'action' => 'deleteVideos'),array('page' => '[0-9]+'));
```

**Controller**

```
public function deleteVideos($id){
        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Apagar videos');
        $this->layout = 'admin';
        $this->loadModel('GalleryVideo');
        $this->GalleryVideo->id=$id;
        $this->Paginator->settings = $this->paginate;
        $gallery_videos=$this->Paginator->paginate('GalleryVideo');
        $this->set('gallery_videos', $gallery_videos);
        if($this->request->is('post')){
            if(!$this->GalleryVideo->exists()){
                throw new NotFoundException('Erro, este video não foi encontrado.', 'default', array('class'=>'alert flashMessageDanger alert-dismissable'));
            }
            $options = array('conditions' => array('GalleryVideo.'.$this->GalleryVideo->primaryKey=>$id));
            $gallery_video_delete = $this->GalleryVideo->find('first', $options);
            if($this->GalleryVideo->delete()){
                $this->Session->setFlash('O Video foi excluído com sucesso.', 'default', array('class'=>'alert flashMessageSuccess alert-dismissable'));
                $this->redirect('/Admin/Dashboard/Videos/Delete');                
            }else{
                $this->Session->setFlash('Erro, este Video não pôde ser apagado.', 'default', array('class' => 'alert flashMessageDanger alert-dismissable'));
            }
        }
    }
```

**View**

```
<h2>Videos <small>Apagar Videos</small></h2>
<?php echo $this->Session->flash();?>
<br>
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
<tr>
    <?php
        $i=0;
        foreach( $gallery_videos as $gallery_video ):?>

        <?php

            echo "<td>";
                echo $gallery_video['GalleryVideo']['iframe'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
                echo $this->Form->postLink('Apagar', array('controller'=>'Galleries', 'action'=>'deleteVideos', $gallery_video['GalleryVideo']['id']), array('class'=>'btn btn-lg btn-danger large', 'title'=>'Apagar Video'), __('Tem a certeza que quer apagar este Video?'));
            echo "</td>";
            $i++;
            if($i==1){
                echo "</tr><tr>";
                $i=0;   
            }
        ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Router:**

```
Router::connect('/Admin/Dashboard/Videos/Delete/:page', array('controller' => 'galleries', 'action' => 'deleteVideos'),array('page' => '[0-9]+'))
Router::connect('/Admin/Dashboard/Videos/Delete', array('controller' => 'galleries', 'action' => 'deleteVideos'))
```

**Controller:**

```
public function deleteVideos($id = null){
....
$this->redirect(array('admin' => true, controller' => 'galleries', 'action' => deleteVideos'));
```

Comment: That makes the redirect but the routes gets diferente from what is in routes.php, it should be `/Admin/Dashboard/Videos/Delete` but it shows `/galleries/deleteVideos/admin:1`, the flash message isn't showing up as well.

Comment: I do not understand why after deletion, you redirect back to the same method. Also, use lowercase letters in your routing: 'admin/videos/ ..'

Comment: I want cake to take the user back to the form and display the success message.

Comment: at visit .../Admin/Dashboard/Videos/Delete, You have delete.ctp view, and within it have a html form?

Comment: I have delete_videos.ctp, used by `array('controller' => 'galleries', 'action' => 'deleteVideos')`. Sorry, I explained myself incorrectly, there is list of videos with a delete button.

Comment: The redirect is there to send the user to that view with it refreshed, and displaying the flash message.